# Python http.server can't reach this page

Tags: python, localserver

I run this code on anaconda prompt:

```
>python -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
```

On my first attempt, it prompted me to a confirmation window whether to allow this or not and I mistakenly clicked cancel. Then the next time I run the code, no confirmation window appears and trying to open the http://0.0.0.0:8000/ gave the "can't reach this page" error. Can somebody help please?

Comment: Delete your history and cache!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419880/connecting-to-ip-0-0-0-0-succeeds-how-why might help

Comment: I created a new env in Anaconda and run the process again. and it work. Thanks

Comment: you should be going to localhost:8000 or 192.168.X.X:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: @JoranBeasley, that's right...